# How does sipp -sn uas work? (Custom scenario)

Tags: xml, sip, traffic

How does `sipp -sn uas` work?
Is it taking the scenario from the uas.xml file?
I'm trying to change in the uas.xml file in order to get another scenario and to add another headers, and I failed.
Any answers or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All scenarios that `sipp` offers by default are actually built into the binary (hardcoded). So, the only way to change them is to first clone the sipp project:

```
git clone https://github.com/SIPp/sipp.git
cd sipp
```

Edit the uas XML scenario as you wish:

```
vim src/scenario.cpp +2004
```

Build the new sipp and install it to /usr/local/bin/sipp (just to be safe):

```
./build.sh
sudo make install
```